# Testing a POST request with specific parameter in Lumen

Tags: laravel, testing, acceptance-testing, lumen

My Lumen app currently responds to unkown values for a `hub.mode` parameter with a 501 response. If there is no `hub.mode` parameter set a 400 response is returned. I can manually test this behavior with cURL with:

```
curl -v --data "hub.mode=unkown-value" http://lumen.app
```

As expected there is a 501 response. I can’t seem to test this with `phpunit`. Here’s my current test case:

```
public function test501ResponseFromUnkownMode()
{
    $this->call('POST', '/', ['hub.mode' => 'unkown-value']);

    $this->assertResponseStatus(501);
}
```

However, a 400 response is returned, indicating the `hub.mode` parameter isn’t being passed by the `call()` method for some reason. Anyone encountered anything like this before?

Comment: Try to add -XPOST to curl params

Comment: Try manually adding it to the input.  `\Request::merge(['hub.mode' => 'unkown-value'])`

Comment: Where exactly should I add the merge? Just putting it after the `$this->call(...)` line didn’t work, and nothing else I’ve tried seems to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
I could solve my Problem by using a Dependency Injection to get the Request instead of using the Facade (Request::capture()). Seems like the Facade does not work with the test? Well ok the Facade is not documented anymore in Laravel 5.1.
hm, dont know what i like more. An (undocumented) half working feature or a simple error Message that the Facade in 5.1 is just not supported anymore.

---

Hi, i am having something similar here. I use laravel 5.1. 
And evetyme i want to call('POST') something i dont get the parameters passed to the corresponding receiver. Also, in the Controller the Request is always GET.

i dont know what i could do wrong when calling $this->post()  as described in the laravels Docs. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#testing-json-apis

Here is my call from the TestCase

```
$response = $this->post('/api/v1/projects', ["name" => "Fancy Test Project" ]);
```

And here the part where i want to "create the thing":

```
public function store()
{
    $request = Request::capture();
    $raw = $request->json();
    $body = $raw->all();
    $project = Project::create($body);
    if ($project) {
        return response($project->id, 201);
    }
    return response("Could not create Project. Malformed Request?", 400);
}
```

What am i missing?